# ejabberd installation issue for Windows -- ./ejabberdctl: erl.exe: can't execute

Tags: windows, ejabberd

I have installed ejabberd 2.1.11 on two machines, one with Windows XP SP2 and one with Windows server 2003 Standard edition. Both with VC++ 2005.

VC++ 2005 was already installed before starting the ejabberd installation.

I have manually locate and run erl.exe and in the eventViewer I got (in both machines):

> Generate Activation Context failed for C:\Program Files\ejabberd-2.1.11\bin\erl.exe. Reference error message: The referenced assembly is not installed on your system.

and

> Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC80.CRT could not be found and Last Error was The referenced assembly is not installed on your system.

Also when running erl.exe a pop-up window appears with the message: "C:\Program Files\ejabberd-2.1.11\bin\erl.exe This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem."

Also when I run ./ejabberdctl got the error:
"
Starting ejabberd...
./ejabberdctl: e:\bin\erl.exe: can't execute: (14001) Error 14001

" There is a problem starting Erlang.If the error you see is 14001, you need to install:
Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 SP1 Redistributable Package
You can download that installer from www.microsoft.com
You can also check the ejabberd Administrator Guide "

But the Visual C++ 2005 SP1 is installed.

Anyone have a idea why this happening?

Thanks in advance for your time.
rgb